# NSPersistentCloudKitContainer error handling

Tags: ios, cloudkit, nspersistentcloudkitcontainer

Sometimes an `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer` will report an error in the console like so:

```
*2020-04-14 16:41:27.725794+0100 ExampleApp[9736:8226377] [error] error: CoreData+CloudKit: -: <NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate: 0x282b944d0>: Sending ‘NSCloudKitMirroringDelegateWillResetSyncNotificationName’ with reason: ‘UserPurgedZone’* [NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate logResetSyncNotification:](1798)
```

In my code I have error handling in the loading of the persistent store but this error doesn't trigger it as this error comes after the store has loaded.

Where do I handle these errors? How can I see these errors in code?